# Partial View with intentionally blank model

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-partialview

Okay, so I've been using .net MVC (and nowadays .net core) for years and have never had this issue... to my recollection.

I've got a parent view with its own ViewModel, and a partial with its own view model.  Now, the razor code that calls the partial does so by string name, and it has no idea what viewmodel it should use because it's dynamic.  Now, when we call a controller method that returns a view that requires a viewmodel and we don't  provide an instance of that viewmodel, MVC wires us up a new instance by default.  However, with a partial view inside of a parent view, even if we don't specify a viewmodel, or intentionally pass in null, we will still receive the error that the parent viewmodel type was passed in when the partial's viewmodel type was required.  I simply want to, by default new up a viewmodel of whatever type the partial needs, without hard-coding it... just like a normal view would do when returned by a controller method...

Any ideas?
For example

`public IActionResult DoSomething() => View();`

With a view calld "DoSomething" that looks like this.

```
@model app.viewmodels.DoSomethingViewModel
<h1>@(Model.SomeStringProperty)</h1>
```

The controller view will use a newly constructed model for reference.

However, if I have another view called "DoSomethingElse"

```
@model app.viewmodels.DoSomethingElseViewModel
<h1>@(Model.SomeStringProperty)</h1>
```

and I change the first view to include a partial of that view

```
    @model app.viewmodels.DoSomethingViewModel
    <h1>@(Model.SomeStringProperty)</h1>
    @await HTML.PartialAsync("DoSomethingElse")
```

By default the partial will get passed into it the "DoSomethingViewModel" from its calling parent.

How can I make the partial use its default constructor without hardcoding something like this.

```
    @model app.viewmodels.DoSomethingViewModel
    <h1>@(Model.SomeStringProperty)</h1>
    @await HTML.PartialAsync("DoSomethingElse", new 
    DoSomethingElseViewModel())
```

I wanted to avoid using reflection in my particular circumstances, and it just seems that there should be an overload that allows you to uses a newly constructed model by default.

Comment: I have a workaround... for now where I added a a property of type Type to an object I pass around in this parent view, and am using `Activator.CreateInstance(flowStep.ViewModel)`  While this works... I really wish MS hadn't explicitly set in the Partial code to use the parent if no model was passed in OR IF THE MODEL IS EXPLICITLY NULL.  I wish it would just new one up if it were explicitly null, or have an overload that allows that.

Comment: In case you wanted to see it this is the MS implementation I'm referring to:`// A value for Model or For was not specified, fallback to the ViewContext's ViewData model.
            return ViewContext.ViewData.Model;`  ref:https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.TagHelpers/src/PartialTagHelper.cs